# Strange deadlock in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

[image]

Can someone please explain to me why this is happening?
why does a non circular transaction causing deadlock?

```xml
<resource-list>
    <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="56015" dbid="28" subresource="FULL" objectname="tableY" id="lock2d8a2e99900" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="72057594083278848">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process2d365b79c28" mode="IX" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process2da8701d848" mode="S" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
    <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="47231" dbid="28" subresource="FULL" objectname="tableX" id="lock2da8775aa00" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="72057594067615744">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process2da8701d848" mode="IX" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
<waiter id="process2d365b79c28" mode="S" requestType="convert" />
      </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
  </resource-list>
```

Comment: thanks @Larnu! for fixing the image

Comment: You'd missed out your code fence at the end, and used 4 back ticks (`\``) instead of 3 at the start (so 3 at the end wasn't closing it). :)

Comment: It is circular. Your diagram seems wrong if it doesn't show a circle.

  process2d365b79c28 has an IX lock on page 56015
  process2da8701d848 is waiting on an S lock on 56015
  
  process2da8701d848 has an IX lock on page 47231
  process2d365b79c28 has a lock on page 47231 but is waiting to convert it to an S lock

Comment: The table-level shared locks contributing to the deadlock may be an indicator that query/index tuning is needed or you're using a restrictive isolation level, like serializable, which is prone to deadlocks by nature.

Comment: Maybe the reason why your diagram is wrong is that the XML has "aprocess2d365b79c28" instead of "process2d365b79c28" - and in fact is totally messed up in that part

Comment: fixed the xml and updated the graph, can someone explain to me why the deadlock is occurring? since both are inserting new records and retrieving a join statement using the newly inserted records?

Comment: We need to see the actual SQL not a vague description of it. Table definitions including indexes are also likely to be needed